# Overfull \hbox in paragraph in tabularx

Tags: tables, errors, tabularx, paragraphs

I am always getting the same error and can't find a solution. I want to create a table in text width. The first and the second column should be centered and the third column is for text until the end of the line. How can I achieve this without an error?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}                        
\usepackage{tabularx}                               
\usepackage{booktabs}                               
\usepackage{ragged2e}                               
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}cc>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
        \toprule
        \footnotesize\textbf{Symbol} & \footnotesize\textbf{Einheit} & 
\footnotesize\textbf{Definition}\\
        \midrule
        $A$ & \si{\metre\squared} & Fläche\\
        $F$ & \si{N} & Kraft\\
        $D$ & \si{1} & Divergenz\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\noindent` before `\begin{tabular}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you noticed, that the left space between table and frame has the same length as the overfull thing.

So there are to possibilities to avoid that. The first one is to use an `table` environment. The code will look like that:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}                        
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ccX}
            \toprule
            \footnotesize\textbf{Symbol} & \footnotesize\textbf{Einheit} & 
            \footnotesize\textbf{Definition}\\
            \midrule
            $A$ & \si{\metre\squared} & Fläche\\
            $F$ & \si{N} & Kraft\\
            $D$ & \si{1} & Divergenz\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

The seccond one is, to use the `flushleft` environment:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}                        
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}    
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
    \begin{flushleft}
        \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ccX}
            \toprule
            \footnotesize\textbf{Symbol} & \footnotesize\textbf{Einheit} & 
            \footnotesize\textbf{Definition}\\
            \midrule
            $A$ & \si{\metre\squared} & Fläche\\
            $F$ & \si{N} & Kraft\\
            $D$ & \si{1} & Divergenz\\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabularx}
    \end{flushleft}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you very much! works like a charm